# Don't show my connection string on my project in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a project in C# using .NET, and I have my connection string in the main page (Default.aspx) but in others works in the same page but using VB .NET the users used :

```
Public mycon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conexion").ConnectionString)
```

and in C# I can't put that, there are some way to don't show my connection string?

Answer (score 10):

You can do that in C#.. it's just that indexers use square brackets instead of parenthesis in C#.

So, **not** this:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conexion")
```

..this:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"]
//                                    ^^         ^^ square
```

Comment: And make sure you have a reference to System.Configuration